# TypeError: 'torch.dtype' object is not callable. how to call this function?

Tags: python, pytorch, dtype

How to call this torch.dtype? because here the error shows it's not callable. before I used floatTensor and it shows the error like this `can't convert np.ndarray of type numpy.object_` and now I using float64 it showing the error `'torch.dtype' object is not callable`. please help with this issue.

```
import torch
    a = torch.cuda.is_available()
    b = torch.cuda.current_device()
    c = torch.cuda.get_device_name()
    d = torch.cuda.memory_reserved()
    e = torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
    var1 = torch.FloatTensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]).cuda()
    var1
    a1 = var1.device
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
    df.head()
    b1 = df.isnull().sum()
    import seaborn as sns
    import numpy as np
    df['Outcome']=np.where(df['Outcome']==1,"Diabetic","No Diabetic")
    b2 = df.head()
    b3 = sns.pairplot(df,hue="Outcome")
    
    X=df.drop('Outcome',axis=1).values
    y=df['Outcome'].values
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
    y_train
    
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    
    X_train=torch.FloatTensor(X_train).cuda()
    X_test=torch.FloatTensor(X_test).cuda()
    y_train=torch.float64(y_train).cuda()
```

this is the error:

```
 C:\Users\vinot\.conda\envs\python21\python.exe D:/python/python_work/pythonProject/diabetes.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/python/python_work/pythonProject/diabetes.py", line 35, in <module>
        y_train=torch.float64(y_train).cuda()
    TypeError: 'torch.dtype' object is not callable
    
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

In PyTorch, you can change the type of Tensor by `Tensor.type(dtype)`, you can check what type you need via [this link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html). Further, I recommend you should check if your GPU is available first and select `float32` instead for `float64` (in most case, 32 bits is enough complexity). So that line should become:

```py
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
y_train = y_train.type(torch.float32).to(device) # change torch.float32 to torch.float64 if you still want to use float 64
```

Answer (score 2):

torch.float64 is a dtype object and not a function so it cannot be called.

To make it into a double float (or at least to make sure it is), I would instead call:

```
y_train = torch.from_numpy(y_train).double().cuda()
```